# What are steps required for making app compliant with 64 bit

Tags: android, jwplayer, android-ffmpeg

As I got an email from the Google play store

> By August 1, 2019, all apps that use native code must provide a 64-bit version in order to publish an update. As of the sending of this email, at least one of your apps* does not yet meet the requirement:

As far I am using as following gradles. If I will use following Gradle files so it will work on 64-bit compliant devices?

These gradle used for taking frames from video files:

```
armeabiImplementation 'com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever-armeabi:1.0.14'
armeabi_v7aImplementation 'com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever-armeabi-v7a:1.0.14'
x86Implementation 'com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever-x86:1.0.14' 
x86_64Implementation 'com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever-x86_64:1.0.14'
arm64_v8aImplementation 'com.github.wseemann:FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever-arm64-v8a:1.0.14'
```

Playing video using JWPlayer :

```
implementation "com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-core:3.6.0"
implementation "com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-common:3.6.0"
implementation "com.longtailvideo.jwplayer:jwplayer-chromecast:3.6.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Get your apps ready for the 64-bit requirement**

All developers: Here is an overview of the steps you will need to take in order to become 64-bit compliant.

Inspect your APK or app bundle for native code. You can check for .so files using APK Analyzer.

Identify whether they are built from your own code or are imported by an SDK or library that you are using. If you do not have any .so files in your APK, you are already 64-bit compliant.

Enable 64-bit architectures and rebuild native code (.so files) imported by your own code.

Upgrade any SDKs and libraries to 64-bit compliant versions, if needed. Reach out to the SDK or library owner if one is not available. We’re working with top library owners on their 64-bit compatibility.

Test for issues locally once you’ve rebuilt your app.

Rollout to your testers using testing tracks for thorough testing.

and much more at this [link](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html).